# Excel how to refence to sheet by sheet name in column

Tags: excel

I have an excel table:

```
Sheet_name  Data from sheet 83, cell A1
83          #REFERENS!
```

Im trying to fill cell with error message above with formula:

```
='83'!A1
```

First cell in another sheet named 83. But i want to do it using column Sheet_name, so i try:

```
="'"&A2&"'"&!A1
```

Which give Reference error. Is this possible without using VBA code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try like this:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'"&"!A1")
```

Answer (score 0):

It work through indirect formula

```
=INDIRECT("'["&B6&"]"&C6&"'!"&D6)
```